# Livros com origens de expressões populares

Tags: discussion, recursos

Reparei que, neste site, uma pergunta recorrente é "qual é a origem desta expressão?".

Alguém sabe/recomenda algum livro (ou outro tipo de suporte) que contenha as origens históricas de diferentes expressões da língua portuguesa?

Achei que seria interessante para a comunidade ter referências de recursos para este tipo de questões.

Answer (score 2):

Tens disponível online o [*Frases Feitas: Estudo conjetural de locuções, ditados e provérbios*, (publicado originalmente em 1908-9; esta edição, 2009) do filólogo brasileiro João Ribeiro](http://www.academia.org.br/sites/default/files/publicacoes/arquivos/frases_feitas_-_joao_ribeiro_-para_internet.pdf).

Vale também a pena ver [*Tradições Populares de Portugal* (1882) do filólogo português Leite Vasconcellos](https://archive.org/stream/tradiespopulare00vascgoog#page/n77/mode/2up/search/velha).

Há também o *Dicionário do Folclore Brasileiro* (1954), de Luís da Câmara Cascudo, que já esteve disponível online, mas ao que parece deixou de estar.